# I Converted log loss formula for multi layered neural network in code but the expected output is wrong

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I have been doing Coursera "Calculus for Machine Learning and Data Science" Course. This is code from the lab assignment. I tried multiple ways (Google, Stack overflow and ChatGPT) but could not find the exact problem my code is having.

This is the first image of the compute_cost function(The code and the expected output regarding this code is pasted below.)

[image]

This is the 2nd screenshot of the code that shows the tests and the expected output of my `compute_cost` function
[image]

**Code for Compute_cost function**

```
def compute_cost(A2, Y):
    """
    Computes the cost function as a log loss
    
    Arguments:
    A2 -- The output of the neural network of shape (1, number of examples)
    Y -- "true" labels vector of shape (1, number of examples)
    
    Returns:
    cost -- log loss
    
    """
    # Number of examples.
    m = Y.shape[1]
    
    ### START CODE HERE ### (~ 2 lines of code)
    print (f"{A2.shape}  {Y.shape}")
    logloss = np.multiply((Y*(-1)) , (np.log(A2))- np.multiply( np.log(1 - A2),(1 - Y)))
    cost = (1/m) * np.sum(logloss )
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    assert(np.isscalar(cost))
    
    return cost
`
A2: [[0.5 0.5 0.5 ... 0.5 0.5 0.5]]. A2 shape: (1,2000)
 Y : [[1 1 1 ... 1 1 1]]. Y shape : (1,2000)
print("cost = " + str(compute_cost(A2, Y))) `
 

Output: cost = 0.34657359027997264. Expected Cost:cost = 0.6931477703826823
```

I tried to write the cost function for multi layered neural network. The expected output of the cost function is not correct. I want to find out bugs in the code.

Comment: please provide code within the question, do not use screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have used brackets wrong

```
logloss = np.multiply((Y*(-1)) , (np.log(A2))- np.multiply( np.log(1 - A2),(1 - Y)))
```

which is equivalent to

```
logloss = -Y * (np.log(A2) - (1-Y) * np.log(1 - A2)) # note extra bracket!
```

and it should be

```
logloss = -Y * np.log(A2) - (1-Y) * np.log(1 - A2)
```

Comment: Yes! it worked. Thankyou. 
(I wonders that is my question negatively rated? )